# Google Spreadsheet Script - Increasing value of a cell in sheet2 before clearing cell in sheet1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Completely new when it comes to scripting etc but managed to get some small scripts working via looking up things here and there, so please bear with me.

I am looking to create a script that allows me to enter a value in a cell in sheet1 that **adds** the value to a cell in sheet2 (so not a simply copy over). Once the value in sheet1 has been entered, it clears itself.

Sadly, I have no script to show you of what I have tried, as this has me completely stumped. If anyone has any pointers or can provide help, it would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Based on below code, I've tried something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');//used for debugging
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//get event object
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Dashboard" && e.getRange("C17") && e.value) {
    let rg = e.source.getSheetByName("Data").getRange("D2")
    rg.setValue(Number(rg.getValue()) + Number(e.value));
    e.range.setValue('');
  }
}
```

Though not getting it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Add B2 Sheet0 to B2 Sheet1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');//used for debugging
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));//get event object
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    let rg = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart)
    rg.setValue(Number(rg.getValue()) + Number(e.value));
    e.range.setValue('');
  }
}
```

Note: you cannot run this type of function from the script editor just paste into script editor, save and go to Sheet1 B2 and type in a number and hit return.  Then look on Sheet2 to see B2 change.

[onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, and it works. My follow up question would be, is there any way to modify this script so that you can explicit say move for cell x to cell y? So say for example: B25 (Sheet0) to C4 (Sheet1)?

Comment: The reason why I am asking is, if I try to change the value "2" in the script, it simply fails to work.

Comment: changing the numbers just changes the cell that it works  on